# jQuery UI accordion not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The accordion normally works when I am just using plain html.

However, I am using dynamic data, so I am implementing Javascript to create `<div>` and `<h3>` tags for the accordion.

I am using this snippet of code:

```
 $('#rangeInfo').append('<div id=\"accordion\">');
 for ( var obj in timeClusters) {
     $('#rangeInfo').append ('<h3> ' + timeClusters[obj].startReal + '</h3> <div>Information</div>'  );       
 }
 $('#rangeInfo').append('</div>');
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#accordion").accordion();
 });
```

Comment: You are missing a `>` for the `h3`

Comment: My bad, it was properly done on the original document, didn't copy correctly. After correction, it still didn't work, but "undefined"'s answer fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's  not how DOM works, you can't insert opening and closing tags separately. You should insert element.

```
$('<div id="accordion">').append(function() {
   return $.map(timeClusters, function(obj) {
      return '<h3>' + obj.startReal + '</h3><div>Information</div>';
   }).join('');
}).appendTo('#rangeInfo').accordion();
```

Comment: Alright thanks, would you mind telling me why I can't do what I did? And why did u need to use `$.map` and `join`? And yeah, if you couldn't already tell, I have very little knowledge of the DOM model.

Comment: @user3ffgfgfgfgfg50064 As you say it's a model, which has it's own rules. `$('<div id="accordion">')` creates `<div id="accordion"></div>`, and `$('</div>')` doesn't create any element. `$.map` iterates through object's properties and returns an array. `join` joins all the array's elements and returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

`</h3 <div>Information</div>`  is missing a `>`

also

`'<div id=\"accordion\">'` can be `'<div id="accordion">'`